# How to write Java code which ensures that a string is exactly 5 digits long

Tags: java, validation

Thanks for taking the time to look at my question.

I am working on a Java tuturial for college which I need some help with.

one of the requirements is to enter details about employees into the system, such as their name, surname , sex etc..    as well as an ID number.

This ID number may not be more then or less then 5 digits long. How would I write the code nessesary to ensure that the user does not enter more or less then five digits?

As well as this it must start with the numbers 1 or 2?

Comment: I'm afraid you are going to have to give us a clue - what sort of user-interface technology does this apply to?

Comment: to the Command prompt screen in Jcreater

Comment: Scanner class (if thats what you wanted to know) :)

Answer (score 2):

Try something along these lines.

```
getID();

String getID() {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String ID = sc.next();
    sc.close();
    if (ID.length() == 5 && (ID.startsWith("1") || ID.startsWith("2"))) return ID;
    getID();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve a check like this using a regular expression [match](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29) on an expression that checks for digits 1 or 2, `[12]` at the start of the string, `^`, followed by 4 digits `\d{4}` and the end of the string `$`.

Another way would be to convert to integer and check that is in the range 10000 - 29999.

Comment: thanks
I dont understand how to write that would it be    
 while(Value = [12]^\d{4})     ??

Comment: @Binyomin, as this is a homework question I didn't post code so that you can find it out yourself :-) Follow the hyperlink behind match, place the ^ and $ markers at the start and end of the pattern, I'm sure you'll figure it out.

Comment: Thanks. I will have a look at and work it out. 
But I like your Second option (checking that is in the range 10000 - 29999) but it seems a bit to simple I think we need to do the more complex option

Answer (score 0):

Guessing that you are using a `TextField` to get the value (ID number) from user, you can make use of the event `FocusLost` to achieve this.In the event handling code, You may get the value at the `textfield` and check it for the rules you mentioned and if necessary, you may use a `JDialog` to notify user.